# Image appended with a tcmid is available in the markup but not rendered on a page

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, multimedia, dxa-1.7, image

Image is generated in the markup but is not rendered on the page. However, if the tcmid appended to the image is removed, the image gets displayed. We traversed through the Binary data folder in the server location and noted that the image is not added to the folder like the other images, when the page is loaded.But, it gets added when we remove the tcmid in the markup. What are we missing?

Code snippet:`<dxa:media media="${entity.heroImage}" aspect="3.3" />`

markup:`<div class="article-image" property="s:heroImage"> 
               <img src="/media/car-insurance-saving-wide_tcm5-
                  388_w1024_h311_n.jpg" data-aspect="3" width=""> 
               </div>`

[image: Component screenshot](C:/DEV/GIT/Component.png)[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJxe3.png)

Errors in the console : 
10:49:34 DEBUG c.s.w.a.d.DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Could not find Binary metadata by url: http://localhost:8080/media/volunteers_on_the_lunch_line_l_tcm5-399_w1024_n.jpg/media/volunteers_on_the_lunch_line_l_tcm5-399.jpg

However,for DXA sample images, the trace looks like :
11:40:44 DEBUG c.s.w.a.d.DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Retrieved BinaryMeta instance: [BinaryMeta tcd:pub[5]/binarymeta[401], image/jpeg, /media/happy_couple_in_front_of_house_xl_tcm5-401.jpg, /media/happy_couple_in_front_of_house_xl_tcm5-401.jpg]
11:40:44 DEBUG c.s.web.content.client.ContentClient - ForwardedClaims is configured./media/img_sfus-quote-start-large-1920_tcm5-350.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include Publish binaries for component tbb attached to your compound template as it uses a PublishBinariesComponent, which calls ConstructFileName of BinaryPublisher.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to rendering Multimedia with a Tridion-managed page.

Multimedia components can be:

1. Part of a component presentation, added to a page with a template
   selected
2. As a linked-to multimedia component within a "container" component,
   which is added to a page
3. In a rich text format (RTF) area within another component

You could also just publish binaries with dynamic component templates and handle the markup and links outside of Tridion.